# Web Developer toolbar and Firefox 4

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-extensions

The Command-Shift-E shortcut to toggle "Edit CSS" in the web developer plugin conflicts with Firefox's new "Group your tabs" option... Keyconfig also does not appear to work for Firefox 4 yet. Anyone have any ideas how this might be easily resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Wait for KeyConfig to be updated, or switch back to FireFox 3.6, or install both FF3 and FF4.